# Why cytotoxic T cells don't kill dendritic cells when they present antigen?

Tags: immunology, mhc

When a cytotoxic T cell (CTL) recognizes a peptide presented in the MHC-1 of a dendritic cell (APC), why it doesn't kill this cell?

I know that initially, in the lymph node, the T cell is inactivated. But eventually it becomes activated and travels to the tissue, where it again finds APCs presenting the offending antigen. So why doesn't the CTL kill the APC at this point?

Moreover, not all MHC-1's of the dendritic cell present antigens from phagocytized cells. Some MHC-1's present peptides coming from the dendritic cell itself, so that if the dendritic cell itself becomes infected with virus or bacteria, it can be killed by a CTL that recognizes the peptide. So in this case, the CTL does indeed kill the dendritic cell.

So my question is, when exactly does the CTL kill the APC? How does the CTL knows that should or shouldn't kill the APC?

Comment: Afaik. if the CTL is not activated yet, it requires a verification signal from a HTL or a very strong stimuli from the APC. Now I don't know yet what happens when it is already activated and meets with an APC presenting the same peptide. Afaik APCs do present the antigens on MHC2 and MHC1 as well, and it does not depends on whether the cell is infected, so I guess there is a way to prevent cell death in these cases. It probably depends on the amount of TCRs activated and other signals as well e.g. stress signals of the APC or cytokins.

Comment: Effector T cells have lower TCR stimuli threshold for proliferation than naive T cells. I haven't found any article about killing TCR stimuli threshold and about what environment is required for successful effector function by cytotoxic T cells. I found that by HIV not infected CD4+ T cells can be killed accidentally by effector T cells so I think the APC can be accidentally killed by the T cells too and the outcome depends on the strength of the TCR stimuli, and other environmental factors (costimulation). It is not clear for me yet how naive and effector T cells differ by activation.

Answer (score 3):

The presentation of antigens on the cell surface is done by two different molecule complexes: The MHCI and the MHCII complexes. These are coupled to different pathways and are recognized by different T cell populations.

The MHCI molecule presents all proteins which are present in the cell on the surface. To do so, peptides coming from the proteasome (where long proteins are digested) are transported in the the endoplasmatic reticulum (ER) by a special transporter called Transporter associated with Antigen Processing (TAP). By doing so, a profile of all proteins expressed in the cell is presented on its surface, including proteins which arise due to an infection of the cell. MHCI is recognized by cytotoxic (or CD8 positive) T cells which subsequently kill all cells which show foreign antigens on their surface (since this is a sign for an infection).

The MHCII complex only presents proteins on its surface which have been taken up by phagocytosis (so here only external proteins are presented). To prevent binding of cellular proteins in the ER (like for MHCI), the binding pocket of the receptor is blocked by the invariant chain. This chain dissociates only when the MHCII complex enter the phagolysosome with its acidic conditions. This makes sure that only proteins which have been taken up by phagocytosis are presented. MHCII complexes are recognized by helper (or CD4 positive) T cells, which in turn can activate B cells to raise a proper immune response.

In theory this should prevent all problems. In the practical life this is different for dendritic cells in a mechanism called "cross presentation". In this mechanism antigens which are taken up by phagocytosis are exported from the phagolysosme and imported into the ER. This pathway also involves the TAP protein. By choosing this way, APC can activate naive CTL which will kill all cells which present this antigen. See references 1 and 2 for more details.

This pathway is important for the immune response to a number of viruses as well as tumors which evade the MHCII mediated immune response by suppressing the MHCII antigen presentation. See references 3 and 4.

It is also important for the stability of the self-tolerance by the deletion of auto-reactive CTL. See reference 5 for details.

References:

1. [Outside looking in: the inner workings of the crosspresentation
   pathway within dendritic cells](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3816/99y5nwg4_pdf.htm)
2. [Cross-talk between the endocytic pathway and the endoplasmic
   reticulum in cross-presentation by MHC class I molecules](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0952791506002494/1-s2.0-S0952791506002494-main.pdf?_tid=5307b164-7421-11e4-a888-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1416864900_c529833ed101d317c69b5391ed9b4d4a)
3. [Role of bone marrow-derived cells in presenting MHC class I-restricted tumor antigens.](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3816/86teuzcg_pdf.htm)
4. [Cytotoxic T-cell immunity to virus-infected non-haematopoietic cells
   requires presentation of exogenous antigen.](http://www.uiowa.edu/~immuno/classMaterial/Immunology%20I%202003/Sigal.pdf)
5. [Exogenous class I-restricted cross-presentation of self antigens can
   lead to deletion of autoreactive CD8+ T cells.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9221753)

Comment: The question was about what happens if an effector CTL meets with an APC, which presents a peptid from the proper pathogen. Why does the CTL not kill the APC? Note that APC can present pathogen peptides both on MHC1 and MHC2 without becoming infected by the pathogen. So I don't think this answers the question...

Comment: I agree with @inf3rno. I don't see how this answers my question.

Comment: I misunderstood the question and have adapted it now. Thanks for the notification.

Comment: The adaptation is in the last paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

You might find this paper helpful in answering your question. It proposes that Memory CD8+ T-cells protect dendritic cells, with TNF-alpha playing a major role in the molecular mechanism of doing so

Watchmaker, P. B., Urban, J. A., Berk, E., Nakamura, Y., Mailliard, R. B., Watkins, S. C., … Kalinski, P. (2008). Memory CD8+ T Cells Protect Dendritic Cells from CTL Killing. Journal of Immunology (Baltimore, Md. : 1950), 180(6), 3857–3865.

It can be found at:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2905219/

Answer (score 2):

Here's couple links explaining this:

1. Allison himself talks about the role of CTLA-4:
   https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327062074_Fundamental_Mechanisms_of_Immune_Checkpoint_Blockade_Therapy
2. Clear explanation of what happens (see Figures 1&2):
   https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329214140_CTLA-4_and_PD-1_Control_of_T-Cell_Motility_and_Migration_Implications_for_Tumor_Immunotherapy

Briefly, CTLA-4 is expressed shortly after T cell activation and serves to protect APCs (and everything else) from excessive T cell activation and proliferation. Also CTLA-4 makes T cell detach from APC and travel to where it's action is needed - into inflammatory sites.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your answer. We generally encourage more elaborate answers, but because of the referencing a +1 nonetheless :)

Answer (score 1):

Major reason – Helper  T-cells induce APCs to produce an endogenous granzyme inhibitor (serpin SPI) by APCs. So APC's are protected from being killed (which normally involves granzyme-induced apoptosis due to perforin release by the cytotoxic T-cell)

Also, downregulation  of  cell  surface  expression  of  the CCR7 homing receptor on activated cytotoxic T-cell.  Not attracted to APC.

Comment: I presume these things (overexpression of the SPI and downregulation of the CCR7) can also be performed by clever malignant cells. Are there examples of this?

Comment: What''s your reference on this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some exciting textbook reference (Janeway 5th ed.):
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK27118/

See Figure 8.14 and compare with text. Whereas the figure shows some presentation of antigen at the site of infection, the text does not explicitly refer to the figure of the site of infection, and says that presentation of antigen happens only after (maybe during) movement of that same APCs from the site of infection to the lymph nodes. It seems to be only there that presentation takes place (and, presentation by dendritic cells means priming, defined by environment of lymph node,  in contrast to presentation by infected non immune cells).

My point is that presentation does NOT happen at peripherical sites of infection which is contrary to the statement in  your question. According to Janeway's wording - taken literally  - before priming in lymph nodes has taken place there is no danger to dendritic cells in presenting at the site of infection. Successful presentation in lymph nodes thus becomes a prerequisite for any killing of  presenting APCs. This looks like some self-regulatory mechanism to me.

It's a different question if, while protecting during the priming process,  the "known" (your question is based on the premise that there is no killing during priming) second signal B7   in presentation induces tolerance for a certain time period. Again, according to basic textbook wisdom, at lymph nodes "presentation is priming". Presentation at site of infection by APC is no priming. Priming means that t-cells are given permission to divide. It is not trivial to see: APCs, dendritic cells, must be protected in lymph nodes "only", as it is "at that point" they are doing their job of priming. When they present the antigens in the lymph nodes they meed naive T-cells that have yet to become cytotoxic - which implies a time lag for cell division and expansion of the t-cell clone. Before naive t-cells have divided and differentiated there can be no killing. The effet of B7-receptor might last that long - within that time lag a few other specific t-cells might presumably have been primed, then the APC might simply not be needed any more.

Some references
Question of  S. Oncosuresh at researchgate at  https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why-Dendritic-cell-are-not-killed-by-T-cells-when-they-present-antigen
It is the "speculative" answer by Ye Tian from the University of Chicago which I feel inclined most to: cp. "... if by then" (they will kill the DC's presenting).

You say, quote: "... and travels to the tissue, where it again finds APCs presenting the offending antigen."

It's a possibility that the assumption that there is presentation by dendritic APCs at site of infection is wrong.
In that case the following reasoning applies:  If there is presentation at site of infection presenting dendritic cells in fact are being "simply" killed as they are not needed any more, as the very fact that they meet primed(!) cytotoxic t-cells shows that presentation in lymph nodes for purpose of priming has succesfully been undertaken "already".